# Where can I ask for an explanation of the differences in the copyright pages in various books published by Springer?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I happened to notice that different books published by [Springer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springer_Science%2BBusiness_Media) sometimes have slightly different names listed next to the copyright © symbol. For instance:

- [Mirrors and Reflections](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-79066-4) by Borovik and Borovik says © Springer Science+ Business Media, LLC 2010
- [Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-27596-7) by Bjorner and Brenti says © 2005 Springer Science+Business Media, Inc.
- [Limits, Series, and Fractional Part Integrals](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4614-6762-5) by Furdui says © Springer Science+Business Media New York 2013

In one instance we have "LLC", in another "Inc.", and in another the place of publication (I think?) "New York". There's also a space between the "+" and "Business" in one instance which is not there in the other two.

I know these are really minor differences that won't come up in any matter of significance. It's just that I'm curious and want to know *why* there are these minor differences. I would expect the name printed on the copyright page to be standardised so I found it surprising to see (what looks like) inconsistencies and typos.

**Is there an SE site on which this question will be on-topic?**

I searched on Law SE, Academia SE and Mathematics SE, and the only related question I could find was the following on Academia SE:

- [Referencing Springer products: what name to use for the publisher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/58891/87949)

but my question is significantly different from it.

Comment: Have you looked at the scope for [writing.se]?

Comment: @Catija Thank you, I just had a look at the scope and available tags for Writing SE. It's possibly on-topic there, but I think I'll first try my luck at Literature SE based on [Rand al'Thor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/278659/rand-althor)'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346828/313042).

Answer (score 6):

You might try [Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/). Use the [publishing](/questions/tagged/publishing) tag. Note that it's only borderline wrt site scope - we haven't had a question exactly like this before, so I'm not *sure* how this question would be received, and it might receive some close votes. But even though maths textbooks aren't on-topic, publishing norms are, so I think this could just about be on-topic.

(Source: I'm a high-rep user and active reviewer on Literature.)

(Or maybe, as Catija suggested, [Writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com) - although I know very little about that site's scope, so I can't really say. I do know they take questions about academic writing as well as fiction, at least.)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just posted my [question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/13789/5387) on Literature SE. I'll see how it goes now. . .